# Entity Framework create query for one-to-many rel

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have two tables:

**Rule.**

```
class UserProfile
{
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public Nullable<int> AddressId { get; set; }

  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
  public int AddressId { get; set; }
  public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get user's address by userId from the Address table:

```
public Address GetAddressByUserId(int userId)
{
   return AddressRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault().UserId == userId);
}
```

It converts to SQL:

```
SELECT a."AddressId", a."AddressLine1", a."AddressLine2", a."City", a."Latitude", a."Longitude", a."Province", a."State", a."ZipCode"
FROM "Addresses" AS a
WHERE (
     SELECT u."UserId"
     FROM "UserProfiles" AS u
     WHERE a."AddressId" = u."AddressId"
     LIMIT 1) = 1
LIMIT 1
```

**The Problem**

The query executes too long!

**Question**

How can I rewrite it?
Thanks

P.S: I know that I can get address directly from UserProfile query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that you can get address directly from User why no to do that?

```
public Address GetAddressByUserId(int userId)
{
   return UserProfileRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId)?.Address;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Worth mentioning that you have a bug in initial query searching by userId. You are always checking first User of given address, so you may accidentally "skip" address you are looking for.
Here is a corrected query:

```
public Address GetAddressByUserId(int userId)
{
    return AddressRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserProfiles.Any(g => g.UserId == userId));
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I think it's not cool to return the Address model from UserProfiles service, so I trying to do it in the Address service.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this?

```
public Address GetAddressByUserId(int userId)
{
   return UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId).Address;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I think it's not cool to return the Address model from UserProfiles service, so I trying to do it in the Address service.